# mysql query wierdness with Lithium from dev to production

Tags: mysql, syntax, lithium

Here's the gist of my problem..

```
 CREATE TABLE `customers` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `chargify_customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `source_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `referer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB; 


## This causes an error. 
mysql> SELECT Customers.id FROM `customers` AS `Customers` WHERE `Customers.chargify_customer_id` = xxx;
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Customers.chargify_customer_id' in 'where clause'


## But
mysql> SELECT Customers.id FROM `customers` AS `Customers` WHERE `chargify_customer_id` = xxx ;

#gives a result
```

What's weird, is that my mac dev environment, the query works.. maybe, I just need sleep and I'm missing something obvious? Please help :)

Comment: Can you try removing table alias?

Comment: If it turned out to be an unrelated problem (your database), you should probably delete this question, as it is unlikely to help any future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Your quotes in this peace of query

```
`Customers.chargify_customer_id`
```

makes MySQL think the hole string between quotes is a column name. Try this:

```
Customers.`chargify_customer_id`
```

You can also do this:

```
`Customers`.`chargify_customer_id`
```

and since these words are not reserved ones you can simply leave the quotes and do this:

```
Customers.chargify_customer_id
```

Comment: Juergen, technically this query is being generated by Lithium itself, should I send them a bug report about this? Any idea why it would work on my mac, but fail in Linux?

Comment: I would say this is a bug. But I have no idea why this is working on your Mac. It isn't working in my MySQL Workbench under Windows.

Comment: I'm going to add some of the PHP code from the controller that's causing this query, so people from #li3 can verify I'm not doing something retarded. :)

Comment: after looking more carefully, looks like the table structure was a bit off in production. Sorry, looks like I had been staring at it for a few hours.